# How to change month to year in dart?

Tags: algorithm, flutter, dart

I'm working on a flutter project and I want to change month to year? I have months and I want to get its year. for example, 16 months is equal to 1 years and 4 months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for exactly converting months to years and months, I don't think you need a library for that. It is just simple math

```
void main() {
  var months = 16;

  var year = (months / 12).floor();
  var remainderMonths = months % 12;

  print("$year year and $remainderMonths months");
}
```

And by the way, 16 months is **1** year and 4 months.

Comment: Thanks bro. This website looks like Stachoverflow